# Is google analytics allowing us to track individual user?

Tags: google-analytics, web-analytics

Help just read this page: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/policy

Please note:: allows Google to personally identify << is this meant, if google can't indentify this user is ok with their policy?

You will not upload any data that allows Google to personally identify an individual (such as certain names, Social Security Numbers, email addresses, or any similar data), or data that permanently identifies a particular device (such as a unique device identifier if such an identifier cannot be reset), even in hashed form. If you upload any data that allows Google to personally identify an individual, your Google Analytics account can be terminated, and you may lose your Google Analytics data.

Answer (score 2):

No, absolutely not. You answered your question: "You will not upload any data that will allow Google to personality identify an individual..." or am I misunderstanding your question somehow?

Well, technically you are allowed to track an individual but just not by using any information that can personally identify that individual.